# google play services has stopped msg

Tags: google, google-play-services

i have an LG Tribute and the google play services has stopped  keeps popping up i have done all the steps recommended to clear this annoying pop up, is there something else i can do that might work?

Comment: If you've really tried *everything*, there's nothing else you can do. But if you tell us what you've tried, somebody might be able to suggest something you haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it very easily.

1. Clear Phone Data and Cache:
2. Stop Automatic Updates on your Device:

[image]

3. Reset your Android Device Phone's App

Hope it will work for you, If you need more then follow complete tutorial, It will fix other [Process Com.Android.Phone](https://www.howtoseeks.org/unfortunately-the-process-com-android-phone-has-stopped/) errors.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings, force-stop Google Play Services, and restart your phone

Answer (score -1):

If your using a phone that supports multiple users.
setup a second user on the phone and update the system files that way...